# Standarizing coefficients from unstandardized coef. without Standard Deviations

Tags: meta-analysis

In the meta-analysis I am including standardized regression coefficients (b). Sometimes, I have not b, and I calculated it from the B (nonstandard regression coefficients)x [(mean Standard Deviation -SD- from independent variable-IV)/ SD from dependent variable)]. However, I found a couple of papers that did not have SD and means, but they have B, SE (standard error from B), t and p-value. Do you know if I can calculate b from (B,SE, t, and p-value).

Comment: Hi Ryben, welcome to the site. I think you need to clean up your answer to make it more readable. For instance - I am assuming "standardized b" means standardized coefficients? Also, please write out what each abbreviation means (i.e. SD = standard deviation).

Comment: In the meta-analysis I am including standardized regression coefficients (b). Sometimes, I have not b, and I calculated it from the B (nonstandard regression coefficients)x [(mean Standard Deviation -SD- from independent variable-IV)/ SD from dependent variable)]. However, I found a couple of papers that did not have SD and means, but they have B, SE (standard error from B), t and p-value. Do you know if I can calculate b from (B,SE, t, and p-value). Thank for your help. I hope now it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then the papers you are including would need to report the the standard error of the mean for both the response and the covariates, along with the sample size for you to compute the standard deviation of each and thus calculate the standardized beta.

EDIT:

The standard error of the mean is calculated as the standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size:

$SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

With a little bit of algebra we can rearrange this to:

$\sigma = SE \times \sqrt{n}$

Therefore you need to know the standard error of the mean and the sample size corresponding to that standard error.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andre. B. In the meta-analysis I am including standardized regression coefficients (b). Sometimes, I have not b, and I calculated it from the B (nonstandard regression coefficients)x [(mean Standard Deviation -SD- from independent variable-IV)/ SD from dependent variable)]. However, I found a couple of papers that did not have SD and means, but they have B, SE (standard error from B), t and p-value. Do you know if I can calculate b from (B,SE, t, and p-value). Thank for your help. I hope now it will be clearer.

Comment: It is, but you should update your question so that others can follow more easily. I will expand on my answer